# Firestore Property is Undefined On Object. for 'list' @ L41

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm writing some Firestore rules and I'm seeing an error message when I try to read the data from a chat in my chats collection. I've seen other posts about this error, but none of them match my situation and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Here are my security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid} {
      allow read: if userIsSignedIn();
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }

    match /users/{uid}/notifications/{notificationId} {
      allow read: if resource.data.recipientUid == request.auth.uid;
    }

    match /bands/{bandId} {
      allow read: if userIsSignedIn();
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.adminUid;
      allow list, update: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.memberUids;

      match /members/{memberId} {
        allow read: if userIsSignedIn();
        allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
      }

      match /links/{linkId} {
        allow read: if userIsSignedIn();
      }
    }

    match /shows/{showId} {
      allow read: if userIsSignedIn();

      match /backlineItems/{backlineItemId} {
        allow read: if userIsSignedIn();
      }

      match /participants/{participantId} {
        allow read: if userIsSignedIn();
      }
    }

    match /chats/{chatId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.participantUids;
      allow write: if true;
    }

    match /chats/{chatId}/messages/{messagesId} {
        allow read, write: if userIsSignedIn();
    }
  }

  function userIsSignedIn() {
    return request.auth != null;
  }
}
```

Here is the Swift query that is triggering an error message (I know this is what's causing it, I narrowed it down with breakpoints):

```
func getChat(withShowId showId: String) async throws -> Chat? {
    do {
        let chat = try await db
            .collection("chats")
            .whereField("showId", isEqualTo: showId)
            .getDocuments()
        
        guard !chat.documents.isEmpty && chat.documents[0].exists && chat.documents.count == 1 else { return nil }
        
        let fetchedChat = try chat.documents[0].data(as: Chat.self)
        return fetchedChat
    } catch Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound {
        throw FirebaseError.dataNotFound
    } catch {
        throw FirebaseError.connection(
            message: "Failed to fetch show chat.",
            systemError: error.localizedDescription
        )
    }
}
```

When I run this query I get this error message: Property participantUids is undefined on object. for 'list' @ L41.

[Here is a screenshot of the Chat document I'm trying to query, which clearly shows that the Chat type has a property called participantUids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5ZBd.png)

I'm pretty stuck and I have no idea what could be going wrong here. This error occurs both in Firebase Emulator and in my actual database. Any ideas?

EDIT: I added some debug statements to the rule, it looks like this now: `match /chats/{chatId}`: `allow read: if debug(debug(request.auth.uid) in debug(resource.data).participantUids);`

Here's what's printed to the firestore-debug.log file when the exception is thrown:

```
string_value: "qvJ5tmKpih3mFkUCet5CPREg3qjZ" // The correct uid of the logged in user

map_value {
  fields {
    key: "showId" // The correct parameter that the query above is using to find the chat
    value {
      string_value: "Kk1NYjptTJITr0pjfVbe" // The correct value of the showId property for the chat that is to be fetched
    }
  }
}
```

What stands out to me is that the only property printed in the log file is the `showId` property. I'm thinking this is because my query is filtering results based on the `showId` property. Does this mean that, because I'm querying based on the `showId` property, my rule must also be centered around the `showId` property? I don't think that's the case, but I'm pretty stumped.

EDIT 2: I figured it out. I think the root cause of this issue is that I wasn't understanding that "rules are not filters", as it states in the Firestore Rules docs. I was trying to query for chats based on a `showId` property, but because my rules don't provide any read guidelines for the `showId` property of a chat, they would just reject the request altogether. Instead, I need to query for chats based on the `participantUids` property because the rules know what to do with that property, but they don't know what to do with the `showId` property.

Here's another quote from the docs that cleared this up for me: "If a query could potentially return documents that the client does not have permission to read, the entire request fails." Because the rules don't know anything about `showId`, it's possible that approving a query based on this property would return documents that "the client does not have permission to read." As a result, the request is denied.

Comment: For clarification what does this `match /chats/{chatId}` resolve to? Is that screenshot from 'chats' or 'shows' or from 'Chat type' as mentioned in the question?

Comment: The screenshot is from a document in my chats collection. The document is of type Chat, which is a custom type that has all the properties listed in the screenshot. Every chatId in /chats/{chatId} corresponds to a document that is of type Chat. I hope that clears things up!

Comment: One of the chat docs does not contain `participantUids`. Can you check that? One is enough

Comment: All of the chat docs contain that property, and I’ve triple checked that the spelling is right a few times now so there shouldn’t be any little mismatches like that

Comment: In the emulator, change it to `debug(resource.data).participantUids` and see what it logs just before the exception, https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.debug#debug

Comment: @l1b3rty I've updated the end of my original post with the log file output. Thanks! I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: The log shows a doc without the `participantUids` property

Comment: @l1b3rty Yes I noticed that, but there is only doc in the chats collection that has a `showId` property equal to `Kk1NYjptTJITr0pjfVbe`. This same doc also has a participantUids property. Do you think the problem is that I'm filtering the query results based on `showId`, but the rule is based on the `participantUids` property? Maybe the rule can't determine that the query should be allowed because the query is relying on a property that the rule isn't using to make any allow/deny decisions?

Comment: Add a condition in your client side query on `participantUids`, use `whereField("participantUids", arrayContains: {youruid})`

Comment: @l1b3rty I'm realizing that that's probably the only way to do it. I was trying to avoid that because it would fetch all of the user's chats for a second time with the current way everything is set up. I think I just need to rethink the structure of how I'm fetching/using chats at the moment so that that doesn't happen. Anyway, I appreciate your very quick help thanks a lot!

Comment: @l1b3rty Feel free to post a version of what you've said as an answer and I'll accept it to give you credit! I'm pretty sure that's how this works, anyway? This is my first SO question so I'm not sure haha, I updated my question with a solution just in case but if you post an answer I'll get rid of my solution in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client side query has to match your rule. So in your case, change your query to:

```
let chat = try await db
  .collection("chats")
  .whereField("showId", isEqualTo: showId)
  .whereField("participantUids", arrayContains: {youruid})
  .getDocuments()
```